# Python ftplib multi-part uploads

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

EDIT: Steffen Ullrich suggests that I use SIZE and REST, how can I accomplish this in python?

My web server running CPanel supports FTP uploads. When I upload largeish files (specifically 61.7 MB) I get a broken pipe error after a while. Uploading small files (like 1MB) goes smoothly. Looking online, I saw something about "multi-part uploads", can this be accomplished with python's ftplib?

In case it matters, [here's my code](https://gist.github.com/d43e11857a875d187a2a).

Comment: The relevant FTP commands you need to use are SIZE to get the current size and REST to continue the transfer at a specific file position. Combining both command should allow you to implement upload in multiple parts or restart after an upload broke.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have a code example?

Comment: I don't have sample code for python. I only know how the FTP protocol works.

Comment: That's ok, thanks anyway.